# How to use interfaces from `d.ts` of another service

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

I am working on queue messaging service. 
We have two services `A` and `B`.

`A` is used publish the queue message and other service `B` is listen to the queue message.

`B` has exposed interface `asd.d.ts`.
I want to use one of the interfaces declared in `asd.d.ts`

My question:
How to use that interface from `asd.d.ts` in service `A`?

Do I need to `npm i` that particular servicer `B`. Just to use that interface?

Or

Do we have any other method which I am not aware of ?

NOTE: I am not using any other functionality from service `B`. Just want the interface.

Comment: `import { CheckStatus, VResponse } from '../../../node_modules/'name'/src/exposed_interfaces'`

I am importing the interface from service 'B' like this. Am I doing it in the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

To be specific, `*.d.ts` aren't interface files - they are definition files. Interfaces can be stored in regular `*.ts` files. To import something from a file it must be

1. Imported from file (eg. `import` keyword but there are others)
2. Public (eg. `public interface xxx`)

To use `*.d.ts` files, you can modify `tsconfig.json` file and say to include specific file or all files based on wildcards. Exaple:

```
"include": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/typings/**/*" // <- this is where I store *.d.ts files
]
```

Comment: I am currently doing the same installing service `B` then using import. So there is no other method?

Comment: Can you post a piece of code? It will be easier to visualize relations.

Comment: Its kind of difficult for me to get code here. its so linked up. but the situation is the above. I want to use an interface from Service B and use it in service A.